# Is it possible to round to different decimal places in excel based on the range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

I want to set up an excel sheet that would round the value to different decimal places based on the range of the value entered. I tried using different formulas but had no luck. The image shows the requirement. Is it possible to achieve it using nested IF? or would I need VB script or similar? Would someone be able to give me an example of a iIF formula I can use at least for two ranges, then I can set it up for the remaining ones.

[image]

Comment: I think possible. Use nested if and round function with proper round digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of simple formulas using a lookup table:

[image: screenshot]

The `LookupTable` is just the numbers from the original table.

The `ResultsTable` has these formulas:

Nearest: `=VLOOKUP([@Sample],LookupTable,2,TRUE)`

Result: `=[@Nearest]*ROUND([@Sample]/[@Nearest],0)`

---

You can even do this as a single formula, like this:

```
=LET(Nearest,VLOOKUP(A2,{0,0.05;1,0.1;10,1;40,5;100,10;400,50;1000,100},2,TRUE),Nearest*ROUND(A2/Nearest,0))
```

Comment: Cool concept. Upvoting...

Answer (score 1):

To get numbers to the proper rounded integer (vs decimal) as the question requests, something like this should work.

```
=if(A2<=1,MROUND(A2*100,5)/100,if(A2<=10,round(A2,1),if(A2<=40,mround(A2,1),if(A2<=100,MROUND(A2,5),if(A2<=400,mround(A2,10),if(A2<=1000,MROUND(A2,50),mround(A2,100)))))))
```

[See example in this spreadsheet...](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nBiJcO0FiTeWbWf4UAd-bGOXgJPzGygmMLJBpLxt1qU/edit#gid=0)

Test results:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

Assuming that the number is in cell A2:

```
=IF(A2<1,ROUNDUP(A2,2),IF(A2<10,ROUNDUP(A2,1),IF(A2<40,ROUNDUP(A2,0),IF(A2<100,CEILING(A2,5),IF(A2<400,CEILING(A2,10),IF(A2<1000,CEILING(A2,50),CEILING(A2,100)))))))
```

Comment: Ceiling won't work. Consider examples for numbers 41, 1030, 381.

Comment: For the examples you mentioned, 41 is getting the result of 45 , 1030 is getting the result of 1100 and 381 is getting the result of 390. is that wrong? because what i understood is 41 for example should be rounded up to the next 5??

Comment: @AbdullahBayounis - The question only mentions "nearest", not "rounded up".

Answer (score -1):

I've interpreted your question based on your words, not the image.  This may very well be wrong but you have another answer so one of the approaches will likely help.

You can do it via the `TEXT` formula.

```
=IF(A3<=1, TEXT(A3, "#,##0.00"),IF(A3<=1000, TEXT(A3, "#,##0"), TEXT(A3, "#,##,K")))
```

Above is a basic example of a few ways to format the cell.

A VLOOKUP would work as well, you just need do that part of it.

Comment: This doesn't produce the results that the OP is looking for.